# Prevent AngularJS from dirty checking several thousand rows each $digest cycle

Tags: angularjs

I have a data source that could potentially be several thousand rows. I want users to be able to scroll through the list and filter it without performance problems. My data source automatically fires an event whenever a record changes.

Currently this data is mapped to $rootScope.datasource.

I would like to be able to isolate this large data set from the rest of Angular's $digest cycle and prevent Angular from dirty checking several thousand rows every time something unrelated happens elsewhere in my app. I want Angular to only $digest datasource when I tell it to (after one of my change events fires.)

I've looked at libraries like [Bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) and [Watch Fighters](https://github.com/abourget/abourget-angular). This is a great option if the data is totally static, but my records are going to change occasionally, and I want the UI to update when I tell it to.

Is this currently possible in Angular?

Comment: Try with https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce .

Comment: Will Bindonce allow me to update the dom after data is modified? From what I understand this only works with static data.

Comment: why are you mapping to `$rootScope` property? Isolate data in a service. Rarely ever need to put data at `$rootScope` level

Comment: Because the same data is shared by most of my controllers. I have a service that fires an event every time a record changes, and the live data is kept in $rootScope so it can be bound to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't watch large dataset. Instead, watch single value which describes dataset state. 
That single value could be incremental counter or hash of you data. If that value changed, watcher listener function will be called.

Another option -- deregistrate watcher after first use and register it if dataset changed.

Also you should try not to use watcher and use `$broadcast` with updated state.

Comment: That's good thinking. How do I make this work with an ng-repeat? Is there a way to do this with Bindonce?

Comment: @ColinSkow There is no way to optimize ng-repeat internal watcher. It's uses $watchCollection so it is always check all items in collection. You can speed up checking with another prefiltered dataset as source object for ng-repeat. That object should be filled with filtered data and updated only if upstream dataset changed. Also you can minimize DOM updates with new ng-repeat syntax: `variable in expression track by tracking_expression`

Comment: That's the direction I'm headed. I haven't tested the performance yet on the kind of data I will use, but may end up creating my own version of hg-repeat.

Comment: [quick-ng-repeat](https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat) can boost up your lists and tables by watching only a single value like described. Also I have to mention [scalyr](https://github.com/scalyr/angular), since it helped us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bindonce and force an update of the UI when you know there were changes. To trigger this update you need to recompile the template. I've done this in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zGTAzsyJ245OiqHyE9gK?p=preview) by 'abusing' ng-include, but you could write a special directive that does just that.

Comment: That's a good idea, but it probably isn't practical on a large dataset because it will cause flicker.